Can I have two the same methods annotated with @RequestMapping with different headers?
I have Controller in which I have:
    @RequestMapping(value = SEARCH_BY_FILTERS_WITH_TYPE, method= {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, headers = JSON)
    @Secured(Permissions.VIEW)
    @ResponseBody
    public AjaxJsonResponseBuilder searchForFiltersWithTypeJson(@RequestBody SearchFiltersWithTypeRequest request) {
        return search(request);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = SEARCH_BY_FILTERS_WITH_TYPE, method= {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    @Secured(Permissions.VIEW)
    @ResponseBody
    public AjaxJsonResponseBuilder searchForFiltersWithType(SearchFiltersWithTypeRequest request) {
        return search(request);
    }

and I have an error while starting application:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'searchController' method 
search.controller.SearchController#searchForFiltersWithTypeRequest(SearchFiltersWithType)
to {[GET, POST] [/search/filters/type]}: There is already 'searchController' bean method
search.controller.SearchController#searchForFiltersWithTypeRequest(SearchFiltersWithTypeRequest) mapped.

Spring version: <spring.version>5.3.34</spring.version>

Yes you can, what is your JSON variable doing? Your other method is also missing an @RequestBody. Do you really need 2 methods?

JSON is just public static final String JSON = "Content-type=application/json";

use produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE instead of what you have now. The headers might be case sensitive. Looking at your error again it looks like you are creating 2 instances of this class somehow. Which will result in this error.

produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE instead of what you have now -> good point, it's better.
Looking at your error again it looks like you are creating 2 instances of this class somehow. Which will result in this error -> If I comment one of these methods then I don't see error anymore but will try to also check it. Thanks

Did you modify the exception as it references the same method name. So your error and code dont' actually match. That being said defining a header should work, have you tried Spring 6 (as you stated it worked in older versions). I see no reason for it not to work as it should match the most specific one.

Yes, you can have two or more identical @RequestMapping methods with different headers. However, you need to explicitly specify different headers in each method. In your case, you specified a header only for the searchForFiltersWithTypeJson method, but did not specify a header for the searchForFiltersWithType method. Therefore, Spring cannot determine which method should handle requests with a JSON header. Specify a header for the second method that is different from the first one to get rid of the error.

oh, that can be the reason!
Can I somehow use header to accept everything except Content-type=application/json which is done in my first method?

@Michu93 Are you interested in distinguishing by the presence or absence of the Content-type header, or distinguishing by the value of this header?

I wanted to distinguish by presence or absence of the Content-type. I tested your solution and it works if I add e.g headers = application/pdf for the second one - they are properly created. Strange thing is that it was working before with spring 4 and after upgrade to spring 5 beans can't be created correctly.

@Michu93 In this case you can use headers="!Content-type". Be careful, headers are case sensitive.

It should work without an additional header as well (it did in previous versions). I would consider this a bug/regression.

@M.Deinum, it could be a bug but when I added for one method: headers = JSON and for second headers = "!Content-type=application/json" then I don't see the errors. If I were creating controller two times I would still see the error that method X is ambigous, right?

It is a bug imho (rather a regression) as it should pick the one that matches the best, which in this case would be the one with headers not the one without as the former is more specific. But to address your other question yes if you register it multiple times you would still have the exception.
